# Prove that the ideal $(x-2)$ is not maximal in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, I want to prove that the principal ideal $I=(x-2)$ is not maximal.

Surely I just need to find an ideal $J$ that contains $I$ plus some other elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. My instinct is to just say $J = (x-2) + (x)$ (not confident this is correct), or any other principal ideal that is not $(x-2)$ for that matter. However, I'm not sure how I would prove $I$ is contained in $J$ without them being equal even if I am correct.

Comment: Your $J$ here actually works.  Indeed, we have $\langle x-2 \rangle \subset J \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  To prove both of these containments are proper, notice $I$ cannot contain the polynomial $x$ (which $J$ does), and $J$ cannot contain $1$ (which $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ does).

Comment: @Kaj Hansen Hmm, interesting. Perhaps I'm being particularly naive here, but it seems for most principal ideals _I_ we can simply find another principle ideal, and add it to _I_ to form a new ideal _J_ which contains _I_ and at least a few other elements. Is there any clear principal ideals which are maximal? It doesn't seem totally clear to me that there is.

Comment: Not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ there aren't.  The only ideals in this ring that are maximal can be written in the form $\langle p, f(x) \rangle$, where $p$ is prime and $f$ is irreducible modulo $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Notice that $f(x)(x-2)$ cannot be a nonzero constant polynomial for any $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Given this, can you think of an ideal that properly contains $\langle x-2 \rangle$ that is *also* a proper subset of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?  It'll be easiest to construct this new ideal in terms of a set of generators (which will include $x-2$ of course), and note that there may be more than one generator as $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a principal ideal domain.

---

In addition to explicitly constructing an ideal that properly contains $\langle x-2 \rangle$, there is another approach.  One can show that an ideal $I \subset R$ is maximal $\iff R/I$ is a field.  I claim that $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x-2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (not a field!).  To prove this, find a surjective homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with the appropriate kernel.  The result would follow from the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: If I simply take the homomorphism ϕ(f(x)) = f(2), that will yield my ideal as kerϕ, I'm unsure how to connect that to proving my ideal is not maximal?

Comment: To answer your second question: that's exactly right.  The reason this is sufficient is due to this result: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Field

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow. So we have the quotient ring is isomorphic to the integers, but this theorem states J is maximal if and only if R/J is a field, which can't be true since the integers are not a field?

Comment: Indeed!  It was your goal to show that $\langle x-2 \rangle$ is not maximal.  That's one way to show it.

Comment: Oh, duh, that was silly of me. I was still wrapped up in the mindset of adding to my ideal. Sorry about that. As for the first method, it seems adding 2 is the problem here? What if I add just the multiples of 3, or the multiples of 5, or anything else of that manner?

Comment: Yes, I just meant adding one or the other.

Thank you for all the help, I learned a lot here. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I made a small error in a comment @SenoritaChad.  To get a proper ideal containing $\langle x-2 \rangle$, you can add to the ideal all the $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-multiples of *any* set of constant polynomials so long as $\gcd(x, y) \neq 1$ for every pair.  This is necessary due to Bezout's identity.  Otherwise, we'd have $1$ as an element of the ideal, and thus the whole ring as well, meaning the ideal we're trying to construct is no longer proper.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field is key here. For example $(x-2,2)$ is a proper ideal containing yours.

Comment: No, @KajHansen, every polynomial in that ideal has constant term divisible by $2$.

Comment: @KajHansen How do you get $1=xf +2g$ ?

Comment: Oops, my mistake; you are correct.

Comment: Sorry not familiar with the notation, is this, as above, just adding the multiples of 2 as constant polynomials to the ideal (x-2)?

Comment: Yeah.  The notation $\langle x, y \rangle$ means the ideal $I = \{rx + sy \ | \ r, s \in R \}$

Answer (score 1):

Applying the isomorphism theorem to the evaluation map $P(x)\mapsto P(2)\in\mathbb{Z}$ yields
$$
\mathbb{Z}[x]\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\simeq\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x-2)}.
$$
This shows that the ideal $(x-2)$ is prime since the quotient is an integral domain, but not maximal since the quotient is not a field.

The maximal ideals containing $(x-2)$ are in bijection with the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, thus are all ideals of the form $(x-2,p)$ with $p$ a prime number.